# Recording sip calls in android with PJSUA

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am developing a sip app with internal recording. I need the both side audios to be recorder internally in mobile itself.

Read several blogs and articles regarding the same. I know the only solution is using the NDK. After a great effort, I compiled and integrated pjsip/pjsua2 into my app with which client registrations and calls are working fine. But, could not record calls. I had tried pjsua's AudioMediaRecorder but since there in no proper documentation I did not understood anything.

@Override

public void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam prm)

{

```
Log.i(TAG, "onCallMediaState: ");
CallInfo ci;
try {
    ci = getInfo();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return;
}

CallMediaInfoVector cmiv = ci.getMedia();
for (int i = 0; i < cmiv.size(); i++) {
    CallMediaInfo cmi = cmiv.get(i);
    if (cmi.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && (cmi.getStatus() == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE)) {
        try {

            am = getAudioMedia(i);
            audioMediaRecorder.createRecorder("callaudio.wav");
            am.startTransmit(audioMediaRecorder);

            MyApp.ep.audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia().
                    startTransmit(am);
            am.startTransmit(MyApp.ep.audDevManager().
                    getPlaybackDevMedia());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed connecting media ports" +
                    e.getMessage());
            continue;
        }
    }
}
MyApp.observer.notifyCallMediaState(this);
```

}

where is this myaudiofile.wav file saved? How can I get it?

above code produces a log like this -

pjsua_media.c  ...Call 1: updating media..

pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call01:0 is destroyed

pjsua_aud.c  ....Audio channel update..

strm0x953fe014  .....VAD temporarily disabled

strm0x953fe014  .....Encoder stream started

strm0x953fe014  .....Decoder stream started

pjsua_media.c  ....Audio updated, stream #0: PCMA (sendrecv)

MyCall: onCallMediaState:

pjsua_aud.c  ...Creating recorder myfilename.wav..

pjsua_aud.c  ....Unable to open file for recording: Read-only file system [status=120030]

media.cpp  ...pjsua_recorder_create(&pj_name, enc_type, NULL, -1, options, &recorderId) error: Read-only file system (status=120030) [../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:443]

Failed connecting media portsTitle:       pjsua_recorder_create(&pj_name, enc_type, NULL, -1, options, &recorderId)

Code:        120030

Description: Read-only file system

Location:    ../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:443
15:52:01.458
pjsua_core.c  ....TX 940 bytes Response msg 200/INVITE/cseq=1 (tdta0x96976064) to UDP 218.248.233.142:5060:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify an exact folder & file for where to save you recording, something like this.

```
 File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

 // Specify a directory for your recordings
 File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "PJSIP-Recordings");

 // Ensure that the directory exists
 dir.mkdirs();

 audioMediaRecorder.createRecorder(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "callaudio.wav");
```

This will be saved in the root folder under the folder PJSIP-Recordings (You can change this to whatever you want).

Also, make sure you request Storage Permissions.

Comment: You saved my life :) thanks alot n alot..
But, It is only recording the other side audio and not my side. Have any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: you need to transmit the capture audio to the media recorder  `MyApp.ep.audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia().startTransmit(audioMediaRecorder)`

Comment: It worked great! Now, I am Having an issue with outgoing calls. Please can you go through this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387292/pjsua2-sample-app-outgoing-calls-getting-403-forbidden-response-with-tcp-connect